# Flashing cell in GridView when it's updated by ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, uwp, datagrid, observablecollection, uwp-xaml

I have a:
`<controls:DataGrid>`
in XAML page in UWP development made in C#, that updates prices from a webservice.
By the ObservableCollection the cells updates the prices automatically.
I want the cell to flash when an update of its value happens.

I don't know how to get last updated cell of GridView by ObservableCollection element, and which event it raises when it's updated programatically.

**XAML Portion:**

```
<controls:DataGrid  x:Name="dgBalances" Height="600" Margin="12" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Info.Balances }" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" AlternatingRowBackground="SlateGray" RowBackground="DimGray"/>
```

**Function Portion:**

```
private async Task UpdateBalancesServiceAsync(ObservableCollection<AssetBalance> balances, MyWebservice client)
{
    //Run like service updating the observablecollection
    while (true)
    {
        // Get All Balances
        var ret = await client.GetBalancesAsync();
        if (ret.Success)
        {
            foreach (var returnedbalance in ret.Data)
            {
                
                if (balances.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Currency.Equals(returnedbalance.Currency)) != null)
                {
                    // If Balance exists and the Value needs update.
                    if (balances.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Currency.Equals(returnedbalance.Currency)).Value != returnedbalance.Total)
                    {
                        _ = CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                            () =>
                            {
                                balances.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Currency.Equals(returnedbalance.Currency)).Value = returnedbalance.Total;
                                balances.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Currency.Equals(returnedbalance.Currency)).LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
                            });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // If Balance exists and the Value doesn't need update, just show the time last checked.
                        _ = CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                            () =>
                            {
                                balances.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Currency.Equals(returnedbalance.Currency)).LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
                            });
                    }
                        
                }
                else
                {
                    // If Balance does not exists it will create the new one.
                    _ = CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        () =>
                        {
                            balances.Add(new AssetBalance()
                            {
                                LastUpdate = DateTime.Now,
                                Currency = returnedbalance.Currency,
                                Value = returnedbalance.Total
                            });
                        });
                
                }
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

Comment: May I know how did you create your DataGrid and update the prices automatically? Can you provide some relevant code?

Comment: thank you, I updated the post adding the code.

Comment: When you get the last updated cell, could you tell us what do you want to do for it and how do you flash the cell? It's better to operate on the model which bound with cell instead of getting the cell directly.

Comment: I want to change the background color briefly and return to the original color. Maybe green color if balance is up or red if balance is down. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to custom cell to create your own column types by specifying the cell templates used to display and then declare a Background color property to bind with the column which you want to flash. For example, I create a Currency column and when the balance is up, changing its Background.

.xaml:

```
<controls:DataGrid Height="600" Margin="12" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Balances,Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" AlternatingRowBackground="SlateGray" RowBackground="DimGray">
    <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        <!--Currency Column-->
        <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Currency">
            <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Background="{Binding CellBackground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Currency}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        ......
    </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

.cs:

```
public class AssetBalance : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    ......
    public SolidColorBrush cellBackground { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush CellBackground
    {
        get { return cellBackground; }
        set
        {
            cellBackground = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

//If the blance increases, change the Background

```
AssetBalance blance = Balances[index];
blance.CellBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Comment: The solution proposed by Faywang, is very near that i want to make, I setted the Color as Faywang tells, then `Thread.Sleep(1000);` then return to previous color. A lot of thanks Faywang!!!